# Error while using ggplot and shiny to get specific values in bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I'm trying to visualize a dataset with ggplot and make it interactive with shiny. I want to be able to see data for the specific state I select. [image]

This is the error I get and the image is an example of what I'm trying to get. 
the code is as follows

`output$barplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data, aes(x = input$bar_x, y = value))+
      geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
  })`

Where `bar_x` is the Name of the state.
The table is as shown below. Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Your files have to be named `ui.R` and `server.R` in order for R to recognize it as a shiny app. Beyond that, it's hard to help you without seeing your code for the UI.

Comment: Will do! and here's the relevant parts of the code @Phil :


bar_x_input <- selectInput(
  "bar_x",
  label = "Select State",
  choices = data$state,
  selected = "IL"
)

page_two <- tabPanel(
  "Bar Plot",
  titlePanel("Page 2"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      bar_x_input
    ),
    mainPanel(
      p("This is the temporary bar plot text."),
      plotOutput("barplot")
    )
  )
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Midwest Data Visualization",
  page_one,
  page_two
)`